# What is the best c++ wrapper for libav?

Tags: c++

Looking for a simple c++ wrapper for libav (ffmpeg).

I would like to use it on Linux (Debian), and looking for something which does not add unnecessary overhead to libav.

I did some research, found some wrappers, but most of them are outdated, or designed for Windows.

I would like to achieve the same thing as ffmpeg, but my output would be a memory buffer (instead of file).

Anyway, ffmpeg's functionality would be enough (actually it is much more than I would need so it might already have the unnecessary overhead).

Goal is to remux an rtsp stream (h264) to fragmented mp4.

Any sample code is greatly appreciated.